# Why is my script is opening then closing immediately when it shouldn't? (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to make a warmer / colder game in python as a project. Currently, when I open the program it closes immediately despite there being several loops and inputs. I have spent a good 2 hours on it, and I can't figure it out. Any tips?

```
import random
Correct = random.randint(1, 100)
Oldval = 50
Newval = 50
while Newval != Correct:
    Newval = Newval + input("How much do you want to move?")
    if (Newval - Correct) > (Oldval - Correct):
        print("Colder!")
    else:
        print("Warmer!")
    Oldval = Newval
Win = input(You Win!)
```

Comment: One obvious replacement is: `input("You Win!")`

Comment: You need to convert the input to Int also. `int(input("How much do you want to move?"))`

Comment: fix you last line (add "") and `input("How much do you want to move?")` returns a string so convert it to int == > `int(input("How much do you want to move?"))`

Comment: Rather than trying to keep the application running at the end by calling `input`, you should run the application in a way so that the window does not close after the application finishes (for example you could start the application from an already opened terminal or use an IDE/editor that allows you to run the application in a tab or window that doesn't close). That way you'll actually be able to read the error messages in case of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to add a string and an integer. Also, your final input didn't have quotes around the `You Win!` string. Here's the code with the issues fixed:

```
import random
correct = random.randint(1, 100)
oldval = 50
newval = 50
while newval != correct:
    newval = newval + int(input("how much do you want to move?"))
    if (newval - correct) > (oldval - correct):
        print("Colder!")
    else:
        print("Warmer!")
    oldval = newval
win = input("You Win!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pylint` tool to detect the error like missing quotes.

`pylink test.py`

`E: 12, 0: invalid syntax (<string>, line 12) (syntax-error)`

You could install `pylint` using `pip install pylint`